# How do I move line without syntax check in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

In phpstorm, is it possible to avoid syntax check while moving line up /down? When I try to move line over several lines, it sometimes decides that it should move some other lines too and leaves code broken.

Comment: You should use "Move Line" and not "Move Statement" actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to use 'Move Line' (`Alt+Shift+UP/DOWN`) and not 'Move Statement' (`Ctrl+Shift+UP/DOWN`)